# How to detect mouse click on menuItem when added via addMouseListener

Tags: java, swing, events, menu-items

Consider you want to close your java application using "Close application" menu item.

3 possible solutions are (using ActionListener or MouseAdapter or MouseListener):

```
menuItemClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

menuItemClose.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});

menuItemClose.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

3 solutions, and only first one fires.

What is the explanation of this? 
Does some other componenets have same behavior? 
How to properly handle events in such cases?

Comment: To be more precise: all mouse events are forwarded to your listener besides `mouseClicked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sounds like the developers of Java languare forget to propagate events from menuItems using `addActionListener`.

No, the developers suggest that you use [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) "to separate functionality and state from a component."

Answer (score 2):

In that example, you never register a `KeyListener`. Anyway, you should only register an `ActionListener`. For more information, see [Handling Events from Menu Items](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#event).

See also:

- [Enabling Keyboard Operation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic)

Comment: mre: KeyListener was a typo, I meant to write MouseListener, I updated first post, sorry for a typo.

Comment: @Vadim, There really isn't any difference between registering a `MouseListener` and a `MouseAdapter` other than the fact that with the latter, you don't have to implement every method.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I understand this - first is interface, and second is a class. But still, why the addMouseListener does not work? Is it due to some inter-working restrictions? I use WindowBuilder Pro in eclipse, and it adds such events to menu items, which don't work of cource.

Comment: @Vadium, I believe it's because `JMenuItem` (or perhaps `JMenu` itself) is a compound component, therefore a certain part of the component may be catching the mouse events, which will keep you completely unaware. But I could be wrong about this...

Comment: Sounds like the developers of java languare forget to propagate events from menuItems using addActionListener :). Ok, thank you for your time answering the question, will use actionListener instead.